# matches yup zip code validate problem with antd form and react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd, yup, react-forms

I'm currently new to yup and I'm working on a project that need to validate zip+4 format, my yup schema for zip validation is like this

```
zip: yup
    .string()
    .required('Please enter your zip')
    .matches(/^\d{5,10}(?:[-\s]\d{4})?$/, 'Zip code is invalid')// need to check again
    .test('length', 'Zip code needs to be between 5 and 10 digits', (val: any) => val?.length >=5 && val?.length <=10 )
    .typeError('Please enter a valid zip code'),
```

also I use custom format function to auto format input (auto add '-' after character 5 if character 6 is availabled and the problem is when I type 1234 (the error show then I type 12345 the error disapear - this is what I want and this work well) but when I type the 6 character, with the auto format function I will have the input like this '12345-6' and when I delete the number 6, input value back to 12345 and show the error. With the ant design library I also use this function to handle input

```
  const handleChangeZipInput = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    let zipValue = e.target.value
    zipValue = zipFormater(zipValue)
    setValue('zip', zipValue)
    form.setFieldsValue({
      zip: zipValue
    })
  }
```

although I try to change regex the problem always the same I hope someone can help me with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

so I finally know the reason why this validation act like that the setValue is synchronous so when I log the value inside yup through test method I got '12345-' and this value trigger the validation so I will need to handle something in the handle function to make it work